# Eclipse Debug Issues While Coding Android Applications

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

I have an application I am writing for Android that basically does a screen scrape of a large table on the web and presents it in a nicer way on the handset. Its 500k of html and takes about 20 seconds or so normally.

When I have my phone hooked up to the computer, I used to be able to just click on "Run" and my code would execute similiarly speedy, as opposed to Debug where it would take 10 minutes to complete.

Now, however, clicking "run" behaves just like debug mode.... I don't want this overhead, how do I get eclipse to stop sending my app to the debugger already? I have searched online and found a couple people with the same issue, but simply rebooting my phone doesn't fix it, and there have been no other solutions posted that I have found.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Are you saying that when you click run, it goes to debug mode and stops at your breakpoints, puts you in debug perspective, etc?

Comment: I don't have any breakpoints or watches set up. I do not get thrown into debug perspective. I get tons of logging in LogCat though and my app takes 20x longer to run than normal.

Comment: "tons of logging in LogCat" suggests that the logging is what's slowing you down.  What's causing the additional logging?  If the VM thinks a debugger is attached, you'll see "I/dalvikvm(  231): Debugger is active" in logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application manifest, there is an attribute "debuggable" for the application XML tag.  Make sure it's set to false.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.test">
    <application android:label="Test App>
      <activity android:name="Test"
        android:debuggable="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```